# How to separate whole folder content by list of extensions in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have source folder and I'd like to have 2 folders with same structure as in source folder, but one with text files only and the other one with binaries files only. The thing is that for some reasons include filter ain't working for me, both destination folder is existing and I don't receiving any errors during script run. I'm using PS 5.1 and running this script as admin.

```
$source = "C:\scr"
$destSourceCode = "C:\temp"
$destBinaries = "C:\tempBin"
$binariesExtentionList = @('*.jar','*.zip','*.so','*.class','*.dll')
#Copy SC
Copy-Item $source $destSourceCode -Recurse -Force -Exclude $binariesExtentionList
#Clean SC new location from binary files without extensions
gci $destSourceCode -File -Recurse | ?{!($_.Extension)} | remove-item
#Copy Binaries
Copy-Item $source $destBinaries -Recurse -Force -Include $binariesExtentionList
```

Comment: what does `my code ain't working for binaries with include case` mean? [*frown*] is the case of the files causing problems or did you mean to refer to `include parameter`?

Comment: Do both `$destSourceCode` and `$destBinaries` folders exist? Are you getting error messages? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54850180/edit) to include that information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$source = "C:\scr\*"
$destSourceCode = "C:\temp\"
$destBinaries = "C:\tempBin\"
$binariesExtentionList = @('*.jar','*.zip','*.so','*.class','*.dll')
#Copy SC
Copy-Item -Path ($source + '.*') -Destination $destSourceCode -Recurse -Force -Exclude $binariesExtentionList
#Copy Binaries
Copy-Item -Path $source -Destination $destBinaries -Recurse -Force -Include $binariesExtentionList 
Copy-Item -Path $source -Destination $destBinaries -Recurse -Force -Filter '*.'
```

Comment: thnx, but it's not working....you script gave very unpredictable behavior

Comment: Have you exactly copied it? E.g. $source = "C:\scr\*" see asterisk at the end?